# iPhone - double parenthesis on ZipArchive... why?

Tags: iphone

I am importing ZipArchive to use on an iPhone project.

When I compile it, I have trillions of errors saying "equality comparison with extraneous parenthesis", pointing to lines like this:

```
if ((level==1))
```

Why is the programmer using double parenthesis? The error goes away if I remove the extra pair of parenthesis. Is it OK to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably just their preference of style. You can definitely remove them.

Comment: OK, thanks. Preference of style? I would say they are probably crazy... :D

Comment: It might seem like too much for you, but if it were to be edited to, say `if((level==1) || (something))`, it'd make more sense. Like @Matt well said, it's just their style.